# when i click on button my app crashes

Tags: java, android

When O click on my button my app crashes. In log cat it says that I can't parseint "" (nothing)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main); 



    ocjena1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena1);
    ocjena2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena2);
    ocjena3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena3);
    ocjena4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena4);
    ocjena5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena5);
    ocjena6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena6);
    ocjena7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena7);
    ocjena8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena8);
    ocjena9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena9);
    ocjena10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena10);
    ocjena11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena11);
    ocjena12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena12);
    ocjena13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena13);
    ocjena14 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena14);
    ocjena15 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena15);
    ocjena16 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena16);
    ocjena17 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena17);
    ocjena18 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena18);
    ocjena19 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ocjena19);

    izracunaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.izracunaj);

    prosjek = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prosjekocjena);



         izracunaj.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             b=0;
        if (ocjena1.getText().toString() != ""){
            a1 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena1.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a1=0;}

        if (ocjena2.getText().toString() != ""){
            a2 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena2.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a2=0;}

        if (ocjena3.getText().toString() != ""){
            a3 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena3.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a3=0;}

        if (ocjena4.getText().toString() != ""){
            a4 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena4.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a4=0;}

        if (ocjena5.getText().toString() != ""){
            a5 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena5.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a5=0;}

        if (ocjena6.getText().toString() != ""){
            a6 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena6.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a6=0;}

        if (ocjena7.getText().toString() != ""){
            a7 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena7.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a7=0;}

        if (ocjena8.getText().toString() != ""){
            a8 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena8.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a8=0;}

        if (ocjena9.getText().toString() != ""){
            a9 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena9.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a9=0;}

        if (ocjena10.getText().toString() != ""){
            a10 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena10.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a10=0;}

        if (ocjena11.getText().toString() != ""){
            a11 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena11.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a11=0;}

        if (ocjena12.getText().toString() != ""){
            a12 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena12.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a12=0;}

        if (ocjena13.getText().toString() != ""){
            a13 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena13.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a13=0;}

        if (ocjena14.getText().toString() != ""){
            a14 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena14.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a14=0;}

        if (ocjena15.getText().toString() != ""){
            a15 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena15.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a15=0;}

        if (ocjena16.getText().toString() != ""){
            a16 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena16.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a16=0;}

        if (ocjena17.getText().toString() != ""){
            a17 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena17.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a17=0;}

        if (ocjena18.getText().toString() != ""){
            a18 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena18.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a18=0;}

        if (ocjena19.getText().toString() != ""){
            a19 = Integer.parseInt( ocjena19.getText().toString() );
            b++;}else{a19=0;}
        double rez = (a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8+a9+a10+a11+a12+a13+a14+a15+a16+a17+a18+a19)/b;
        String rezString= Double.toString(rez);
        prosjek.setText(rezString);


        }});

     }







@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: if it says it cant parse an empty string it means you pass an empty string to Integer.parseInt, read the logcat you will found which call cause the exception

Comment: Instead of `ocjena18.getText().toString() != ""` I would use the String-method `!isEmpty()`. Example: `new String("") != ""`

Comment: it also says this..04-25 19:49:00.024: E/AndroidRuntime(23843): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "".. but i put if there which says it my edittext is "" than it doesnt do parseint

Comment: This will always crash if all of your if conditions are false as you will try and divide by 0. Make sure to add logic that will prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `==` or `!=` for string comparisons. You're comparing object references and not values.

Use `equals()`, or in case of comparing to `""`, `isEmpty()`.

Comment: and what i put in .equal() brackets?

Comment: Instead of `a == b` you would write `a.equals(b)`. Instead of `a != ""` write `!a.isEmpty()`.

Comment: i changed that but now my a1,a2...doesnt grab numbers when i input them, and my b is not increasing it stays 0

Answer (score 0):

Use

`if (!ocjena1.getText().toString().equals(""))`

instead of

`if (ocjena1.getText().toString() != "")`

Comment: Now LogCat says that i can t divide by zero?

Comment: Have you try to print the result of `ocjena1.getText().toString()` and  the others? Have any not blank?